# Finding the value of $|DB| \cdot |DC|$

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given that $ABC$ is a triangle, $|AD|  = 9$, $|AB| = |AC| = 6$. Find the value of $|DB| \cdot |DC|$

Since $|AB| = |AC| = 6$, I thought that $|BC| = 6$. However, that truly seems to be wrong. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone take a look?

Comment: $|BC|=6$ only if $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle

Comment: @gd1035 Yes, I missed that.

Comment: You might try Law of Sines or Law of Cosines.

Comment: @John That would be tough for me. However, I can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\angle ABC=\alpha$. Then in $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ADB$, by the Law of Cosine, one has
$$ |AC|^2=|AB|^2+|BC|^2-2|AB||BC|\cos\alpha \tag{1}$$
and
$$ |AD|^2=|AB|^2+|DB|^2-2|AB||DB|\cos(180^\circ-\alpha). \tag{2}$$
From (1), one obtains
$$ \cos\alpha=\frac{|BC|}{12}\tag{3}$$
and from (2), one obtains
$$ \cos\alpha=\frac{45-|DB|^2}{12|DB|}.\tag{4}$$
Hence from (3) and (4), one has
$$ \frac{45-|DB|^2}{12|DB|}=\frac{|BC|}{12}\tag{3} $$
or
$$ |DB||BC|+|DB|^2=45 $$
which implies
$$ |DC||DB|=45. $$

Answer (score 4):

## This may be the simplest solution...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be the mid-point of $BC$, let $u = |DM|$, $v = |BM| = |CM|$ and $h = |AM|$.
Since $|AB| = |AC|$, $\triangle DAM$ and $\triangle BAM$ are right angled triangles. This leads to

$$u^2 + h^2 = |DA|^2 = 9^2\quad\text{ and }\quad v^2 + h^2 = |BA|^2 = 6^2$$
As a result,

$$|DB||DC| = (u-v)(u+v) = u^2 - v^2 = (u^2+h^2) - (v^2+h^2) = 9^2 - 6^2 = 45$$